# Attribute error while exporting data from app engine using Remote APi

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Use the example code from app engine will give an attribute error. The more strange thing is,
When the batch_size is 100, the first fetch will give an error while if it were set to 10, the second fetch will give the error, when the batch_size is 1, the 25th fetch will give the error. Is it due to the problem of remote API?

Python version: 2.7

App engine sdk version: 1.9.6

```
query = MyModel.all()
entities = query.fetch(100)
while entities:
    for entity in entities:
        # Do something with entity
    query.with_cursor(query.cursor())
    entities = query.fetch(100)
```

---

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "migrate.py", line 77, in <module>
    entities = query.fetch(batch_size)
  File "/home/kamel/Library/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2157, in fetch
    return list(self.run(limit=limit, offset=offset, **kwargs))
  File "/home/kamel/Library/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2326, in next
    return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
  File "/home/kamel/Library/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1435, in from_entity
    entity_values = cls._load_entity_values(entity)
  File "/home/kamel/Library/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1413, in _load_entity_values
    value = prop.make_value_from_datastore(value)
  File "/home/kamel/labola/src/model/properties.py", line 295, in make_value_from_datastore
    return pickle.loads(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
AttributeError: class Reference has no attribute '__new__
```

Comment: Seems to be corrupt data. What happens then when you fetch from the 20th record onwards?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when trying to unpickle python3 pickles under python2. The problem was linked to new-style classes becoming default in python3. ([source](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-July/582053.html))

Solution for me was to replace `class AClass:` by `class AClass(object):`

Comment: But I only use python 2.7. As some of them can be pickled while some of them can not be pickled, I dont think the reason is this.